# How can I intercept all calls to methods in a WCF .svc service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Ive got a WCF service which has multiple web methods in it. I want to be able to intercept the request on all methods and look at the Ip address. Id rather not put the logic into a method call at the top of each called web method is there a way to intercept all calls to these methods from one place?

If it was a page I would write a base page object but im nout sure if there are events raised on a wcf call?

Comment: You can use the inspectors in the WCF [Inspectors](https://web.archive.org/web/20120207232924/http://cgeers.com:80/2008/11/09/wcf-extensibility-parameter-inspectors/)

Comment: The comment link above from @dhinesh seemed to load a page with malware and wanted me to install a Chrome Extension. I've reported it to the moderator.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you remove the asp.net tag because your question is much broader than asp.net and can be very useful to C# coders and VB coders too with .NET.

Answer (score 3):

WCF allows you to implement interceptors that are added to the stack. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751495.aspx) for an example. I´m not sure whether this allows you the extract the senders IP but I think it´s worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement IDispatchMessageInspector and do something like this.

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, 
IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty remoteEndpoint = request.Properties
    [RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

        //remoteEndpoint.Address will give you the address.  

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to attach this to the WCF service before the `host.Open()` call? The only thing I saw was that I had to create a special behavior, binding, and then message inspector. I ripped my hair out trying to figure this out and ultimately gave up. Then I discovered `ServiceAuthorizationManager`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Custom Behaviors, they are part of WCF Extensibility features. Here's more information: [Extending WCF with Custom Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a clever way to do this with the `ServiceAuthorizationManager`, and it's far easier than all the seriously hard work of the `IDispatchMessageInspector`.

Create a class in your WCF Service project like so:

```
public class MyServiceAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
  protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
  {
    string classMethod = operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.Action;
    if (classMethod.Contains("/transfer/Get"))
    {
      return true; // because someone is simply updating a client service reference
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Class Method Call: {0}",classMethod);
    // do something with operationContext here as you need to inspect stuff
    // return true if you want this class method call to succeed and go through
    // return false if you want this class method to fail on the client
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then, in your service, right before your `host.Open()` call, add the link to `MyServiceAuthorizationManager`.

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyProject.Service1));
host.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = new MyServiceAuthorizationManager();
host.Open();
```

Now when you test your client connections, you'll notice that the console outputs what class method was called. You can also work against all the stuff in the operationContext object.

One way I use this is for a security header check. In my client, I add a header. Then, in the service, in this `CheckAccessCore()` call, I verify that this custom header exists. If it doesn't, then I return false. This is one more layer of protection that keeps the hackers out, and is great for the limited security in Named Pipes configurations too. If you're wanting to also do that, then [click here](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1075) for more information on how to add custom headers that automatically get sent on every client's method call on the service.

And note, among all this, I didn't have to mess with behaviors, claims, listeners, or message dispatches. I also didn't need to edit my WCF Configuration.

Note the string check for `/transfer/Get` above. This is important if you're doing header checks as a security mechanism like I was. If you don't have that condition and return true, then your WCF client IDE can't update its `ServiceReference` because the IDE doesn't know about that extra header (if you're adding a custom header and not specifying that header in the WCF client's app.config). Otherwise, you'll get an error `The URI prefix is not recognized`.